# Calling an API with OAuth2 C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0

I have an API given by the client.I have to call the method using oauth2 from c# mvc.

I am using the following code to call api

```
 String secret = @"password";
            NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
            parameters.Add("client_id", "clientid");
            parameters.Add("client_secret", secret);
            parameters.Add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
            parameters.Add("pagesize", "3");
            parameters.Add("pageno", "1");


            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            var result = client.UploadValues("http://api.test.com/getcustomers",parameters);

            var response = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
```

Pagesize and pageno are the parameters for this method.

When I run this code,I am getting error {"error":"invalid_request"} "Check the \"access token\" parameter."} "

Please let me know whether calling the API with OAUTH2 is correct

Comment: Don't you need to use the `client_id`, `client_secret` and `grant_type` to request an `access_token` first, and then pass that to the call?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get the access token from the API by passing the user credentials and then inject this token as header to every call to this API.

The API will be having a endpoint to get the token by submitting the credentials. You have to get in touch with the API provider or refer their documentation to find this.